# File not found when trying to deploy a smart contract with Hardhat

Tags: npx, hardhat, uniswap

I have been working through [this](https://github.com/Nachoxt17/Arbitrage-Bot-between-UniSwap-and-SushiSwap-with-FlashLoans) project and at the point of trying to deploy the smart contract to the Roptsten test network, with connection through Infura.

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy the ArbitrageFlashLoaner SC to Ropsten through Infura.io.
Hardhat v2.7.1.

[image]
*HardhatError: HH404: File @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol, imported from contracts/UniswapV2Library.sol, not found.*

So I understand that it is unable to find `@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol` from contracts/UniswapV2Library.sol, but I see that `SafeMath.sol` is in the relative path of `node_modules`:

[image]

`UniswapV2Library.sol` is a folder containing .json:

[image]

And the contents of `UniswapV2Library.json`:

```
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "UniswapV2Library",
  "sourceName": "contracts/UniswapV2Library.sol",
  "abi": [],
.
.
.
```

I'm stuck on what the path issue is in running `npx hardhat...`.  The stacktrace doesn't really hep me.  Is there a way to run this through some sort of IDE or put a watch on variable to see what the actual paths and variables are in all the files it uses (step through the process) while it's running, or where it's looking?

Answer (score 1):

`@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol` was the path of the SafeMath.sol contract before the repository structure reorganization of the 22nd February 2021

(you can check that in detail here [github.com/OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/24a0bc23cfe3fbc76f8f2510b78af1e948ae6651#diff-f4b1737177aad965d94530b54ac4001a2e1f5fe6e4e34bafe023310cea599eca) )

Now the new path is `@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol`.

So if I am not mistaken you can just change the path of your library import in your contract and it should work.